# Python init doesn't see class variable

Tags: python, class, scope, visibility

I'm feeling more dumb than usual, sorry.  Can someone put me out of my misery and explain why `__init__` can't see class variable `s`?

Thanks.

```
class C:
    s = "but why"

    def __init__(self):
        print(s)

c = C()   
#global DEFAULT_STRING = "(undefined)"
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/pvdl/Desktop/FH.sp18python/hw/7/test5.py", line 7, in module
    c = C()
    File "/Users/pvdl/Desktop/FH.sp18python/hw/7/test5.py", line 5, in __init__
    print(s)
NameError: name 's' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: because s is not defined for init
try print(self.s)

Comment: You need to use self.s - the function scope isn't nested in the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

's' is declared as class level variable. It is similar to static variable in JAVA. Variable 's' will be shared by all instances of class C. Hence it can be also accessed using class name(C in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `self`, or the class name, to access the class variable `s`

```
class C:
    s = "but why"

    def __init__(self):
        print(C.s, self.s)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    c = C()
```